# Select 2 column in 2 rows in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data in the following format :

```
ID          Vendor Name     Company Name

1                 VendorA         CompanyA

2                 VendorB         CompanyB

3                 VendorC         CompanyC
```

I want in the following format

```
ID                                     CompanyDetails     
1                                          CompanyA                                

1                                          VendorA                               

2                                          CompanyB

2                                          VendorB 

3                                          CompanyC

3                                           Vendor C
```

i have used Union all but did not work , 
please help me write an sql script for this

thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID,    CompanyDetails
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, VendorName As CompanyDetails, 2 as Tag
    FROM tableName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, CompanyName, 1 As Tag
    FROM tableName
) Z
ORDER BY ID, Tag
```

Comment: i had tried this but Union all alters the sequence.
i print Compoany Name then Vendor Name for some rows and reverse the sequence for some other rows

Comment: Check edited answer , the Tag column used in ORDER By will cxause Comapy Name to come first and then VendorName for each ID

Comment: For what rows you want sequence changed ? Specify what dou mean

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ID, [Vendor Name] from table
union all
SELECT ID, [Company Name] from table
Order by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help you

```
select * into #tab from(
select 1 ID, 'VendorA' as [Vendor Name], 'CompanyA' [CompanyName]
union all
select 2, 'VendorB', 'CompanyB'
union all
select 3, 'VendorC', 'CompanyC'
)as a


select id,[Vendor Name] from #tab
union all
select id,[CompanyName] from #tab
order by  ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an Order to keep the sequence.

```
SELECT ID, CompanyDetails
FROM (
    SELECT ID, CompanyName AS CompanyDetails, 1 AS Ord
    FROM #table
    UNION
    SELECT ID, VendorName, 2 AS Ord
    FROM #table


) A
ORDER BY ID, Ord
```

Answer (score 0):

By using cross apply and NTile also we can achieve

```
 Select ID,CompanyDetails 
        from (
Select NTILE(6)OVER(PARTITION BY COL ORDER BY COL DESC )ID ,
T.VAL As CompanyDetails 
            from (
select COL,VAL from  #Table1
CROSS APPLY(VALUES 
    ('Vendorname',[Vendor Name]),
    ('CompanyName',[CompanyName]))CS(COL,VAL))T)TT
    ORDER BY ID
```